# Show that $\{A^{C}: A\subset X,\bar{A} = A\}$ is a topology

Tags: general-topology

I'd appreciate some help with the following task since it's the first time I am dealing with topologies I am stuck:$\\$

Show that the set $\{A^{C}: A\subset X,\bar{A} = A\}$ defines a topology on $X$ in which the sets $A$ with $A=\bar{A}$ are closed.

To show that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are elements of this set is easy - i am stuck with the properties of intersections and unions of subsets.

Comment: Since you can talk about closed sets the space $X$ obviously already comes with a topology. Can you figure out what the open sets of that topology are?

Comment: Well, if $A$ with $A=\bar{A}$ are closed their complements $A^{C}$ are  open sets.

Comment: So you mean since mentioned set is the set of all open subsets of X I just need to show that every intersection (countable many subsets) and union of arbitrary subsets of X is open?

Comment: No. How do you define topology?

Comment: let me put it this way. As remarked earlier, $X$ already comes with a topology, that is a set $\tau$ of subsets which are called open and fulfil certain requrements. What is the relation of $\tau$ to the set for which you are supposed to prove it is a topology?

Comment: Use DeMorgan's laws.  That however is the hard way.  The easy way is to note that all the complements of closed set is all the open sets.

Comment: I don't know if i get your point. A topology is a subset of the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and the sets in the topology are called open. So far this fits your description of $\tau$ . Since $\{A^{C}: A\subset X,\bar{A} = A\}$ is the set of all complements of closed sets (hence the set of all open sets in $X$) the relation is: $\tau \subset \{A^{C}: A\subset X,\bar{A} = A\}$

Comment: Why only $\subset$? Which set is in the right hand side which is not in $\tau$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma = \{A^C : A\subset X,\, A = \bar A\}$ and $\tau$ the topology on $X$ (which has to exist and you need to know in order to say what $\bar A$ is).

Then each $U\in \sigma $ is open as the complement of a closed set. On the other hand if $U\in \tau$ then the complement of $U$ is closed so it satisfies $U^C = \bar {U^C}$ which implies$U\in \sigma$.

Consequently $\sigma = \tau$ and, since $\tau $ is a topology, so is $\sigma$.